# How to populate a docusign template using a C# dictionary?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

How can I populate a docusign template using a C# dictionary via the docusign .Net client?

I read somewhere a docusign template with custom html but could not find any examples online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Envelope object has a couple of fields you will need:

TemplateId - is like an EnvelopeId a GUID for a unique template

TemplateRoles - is a collection of TemplateRole objects that represents the roles/recipients for this template.

In order to get this information for a given template - you would need to call use the Template class and call the GetTemplate() method/API to get all information for a template. this would include the roles/recipients (As well a more things in the json, which we just pass back as is) here is the important things:

```
       var recipients = json["recipients"];
       var subject = (string)json["emailSubject"];
       var blurb = (string)json["emailBlurb"];
```

I can share a bit more code of looping through the recipients and adding them to the TemplateRoles if you want. Let me know if this is the direction you want to go and how else I can help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Inbar. I am already using the Docusign .NET client and populating string type tabs within the docusign template.

    var tabs = new List<RoleTextTab>();
    tabs.AddRange(new[]
            {
                new RoleTextTab
                {
                    tabLabel = "Client.Mailing.FullAddress", 
                    value = contract.GetClientAddress()
                } 
...
This works perfectly for simple types. My question is specifically about passing complex types (like a Dictionary<string, string>) into one RoleTextTab within the Docusign .NET client.

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do ? I don't think the library right now supports this from a pure API perspective but I don't understand the goal. Are you just looking for a shortcut to add many tabs at once?

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do. My variable is actually an schedule. A list of Date, Amount pairs.

The number of items in the schedule is not known before hand. I need to get the "schedule" populated in the template for the signer to sign.

Let me know if you need to clarify further...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @PMG I don't believe we have anything that supports this right now. You will have to write additional code to accomplish this. I think you can still use the nuget to do this and add code that transforms your dictionary into the list of Tabs the template expect but if you can also just grab the code from github and modify it this way if you prefer

Comment: Inbar. I am not opposed to writing more code :). I just don't see how I can populate this static list of Tabs with a dynamic set of schedule items. Do you have an example that even demonstrates this remotely? I also speak pseudo-code... :)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: not sure what you mean by static and dynamic. When you create an envelope, things must be static, they cannot change later. If that's what you mean - you cannot do it.

Comment: That is not what I mean. I will have dynamic number of items in my schedule list, set at run time. Once set it will not change. How do I feed this list to a template Tab. I am okay to use the bare bones rest API for this.

Comment: Ping! Inbar or anyone from Docusign. Can you please help me here?

Comment: a single tab would include many items from a list? I don't understand how? would you serialize them into the tab?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Inbar.

That is precisely the question. I have a list of items, the number of items will be determined at runtime (and will never change). How can I populate this list within a docusign template, using any technology set. I can serialize it to whatever format docusign can work with. HTML, JSON, XML etc...

Comment: well, tags were not designed for developers, they were designed for people. So, we have a text tag that you can put text it and we don't really care what the test is. It will look ugly, not sure that matters to you. You can also dynamically add tags to an envelope, even if it was created from Template. It all depends on what the end goal is. Tags are typically visual elements, so if you don't care what the document looks like - then all options are the same, but if you do - you should consider it.

Comment: Ideally the the document that the signer receives will have a table with my schedule (list of date, amount pairs) in it. What would be the best way to achieve it? I do care what the document looks like. I use Docusign so that my end users sign a professional looking document :)

Comment: Perfect, I now finally understand what you're trying to do :)
So, I think, you would need to modify your document itself dynamically. I haven't seen your doc but I Assume if the table has a variable number of times - the document would not look the same if it has 2 or 10 items for example (more space etc.) so, you would need to generate the doc itself on the fly. You can use HTML or OOXML etc. depending on how sophisticated and "nice" your want the outcome to be. This part is not DocuSign specific, but I'll happy to point you in the right direction if you need help with that.

Comment: now, using a template in DocuSign, the document can be still provided using an API call and you can even do this with the .NET SDK/Nuget. You just call the AddDocument() method after you created your envelope from a template (And this template can either have a mock document that you remove or replace or maybe you have more than 1 document. There's a way in the API to just replace part of a document, I believe, but not through the SDK/Nuget.
Finally, you'll add your tags dynamically, you'll need to know the doc #, page # and x/y coordinates or you can use an anchor. Either way - it can be done

Comment: Finally, we are communicating :) That is great news. Is there any part of your documentation which covers what you are talking about. Talking specifically about your solution, did you mean I generate a HTML / Pdf document based on my C# dictionary and attach the doc as part of the docusign template for my users to sign? This is getting exciting...

Comment: yup, that's exactly what I meant. I don't think you need any documentation, like any good developer, you can just plunge in :)
Basically, the issue is this work cross platforms and systems and documentations. I would start by generating a document and if that works - move to use DocuSign with the generated document. That latter part is where you'll need my help (or not, it's really very simply)

Comment: Thanks Inbar. I will mark your reply as the answer. - Regards!